# Fork waitpid/status/WIFEXITED? how to do a while will the child is running?

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

I want to do a fork, and repeat some code will the child is running,

something like

```
for(i=0;i<pn;i++) {

r=fork()
if(r==0) { do child code }
else { 
while ( child is running ) { do some code }
}}
```

can i achieve that with wait(&status) or similar? or is there an easier way?

Comment: If you set the timeout to 0 then it will wait for up to 0 seconds i.e. it won't wait.

Comment: don't get what you are trying to say

Comment: Oops, I thought waitpid had a timeout argument. But it does have an options argument. Pass the option WNOHANG.